# Huge delay when socketing in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, delay

(UPDATED CODE)
I'm trying to make clients communicate with server (I've made simple client-server apps, like a chatroom). The communication is created, but there is a huge delay (I send coordinates from the client to the server). It's over 10 seconds (sometimes even more). What could be the problem?
The client:

```
    public class GameComponent extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int WIDTH = 320;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 240;
    private static final int SCALE = 2;

    private boolean running;

    private JFrame frame;
    Thread thread;

    public static final int GRID_W = 16;
    public static final int GRID_H = 16;

    private Socket socket;
    private DataInputStream reader;
    private DataOutputStream writer;

    private HashMap<Integer, OtherPlayer> oPlayers;
    private ArrayList<OtherPlayer> opList;
    private int maxID = 1;

    private int ID;

    Player player;

    public GameComponent() {
        //GUI code..

        oPlayers = new HashMap<Integer, OtherPlayer>();  //Hash map to be able to get players by their ID's
        opList = new ArrayList<OtherPlayer>();  //And an array list for easier drawing

        setUpNetworking();

        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        if (running)
            return;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        player = new Player(GRID_W * 2, GRID_H * 2);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (!running)
            return;
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {  //The main loop, ticks 60 times every second
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double nsPerTick = 1000000000D / 60D;

        int frames = 0;
        int ticks = 0;

        long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double delta = 0;

        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
            lastTime = now;

            boolean shouldRender = true;

            while (delta >= 1) {
                ticks++;
                tick(delta);
                delta -= 1;
                shouldRender = true;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (shouldRender) {
                frames++;
                render();
            }

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000) {
                lastTimer += 1000;
                frames = 0;
                ticks = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void tick(double delta) {  //main logic
        player.move();
        try {
            writer.writeInt(ID);     //I send the player data here (id, x, y)
            writer.writeInt(player.getX());
            writer.writeInt(player.getY());
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void render(Graphics2D g2d) {
        //rendering the stuff

        for (OtherPlayer i : opList) {  //drawing a black rectangle for every other player
            g2d.fillRect(i.getX(), i.getY(), GRID_W, GRID_H);
        }
    }

    private void render() {
        //more rendering...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameComponent();
    }

    class TKeyListener implements KeyListener {
        //movement methods...
    }

    private void setUpNetworking() {  //This is where I make my message reader and data IO
        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5099);
            reader = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            writer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Thread rT = new Thread(new msgReader());
            rT.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class msgReader implements Runnable {  //where I read messages
        public void run() {
            try {
                ID = reader.readInt();   //when I connect, I get an id from the server

                while(true) {   //my main loop
                    int oid = reader.readInt();   //get the read data id
                    int ox, oy;

                    ox = reader.readInt();   //get the read player's x and y
                    oy = reader.readInt();

                    if (oid != ID){   //If not reading myself
                        if (oPlayers.containsKey(oid)) {   //If a player with this id exists
                            OtherPlayer op = (OtherPlayer) oPlayers.get(oid);
                            op.setX(ox);  //set it's x, y
                            op.setY(oy);
                        } else {  //if it doesn't exist, create him
                            OtherPlayer op = new OtherPlayer(ox, oy);
                            opList.add(op);
                            oPlayers.put(oid, op);
                        }
                    }
                    maxID = reader.readInt();  //Allways read the highest current id from server
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the server:

```
public class ServerBase {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    ArrayList<DataOutputStream> clients;
    private int id = 1;
    SyncSend ss = new SyncSend();

    class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private Socket soc;
        private DataInputStream reader;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int id;
        private boolean run = true;

        public ClientHandler(Socket s) {
            soc = s;
            try {
                reader = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            try {               
                while (run) {
                    id = reader.readInt();
                    x = reader.readInt();
                    y = reader.readInt();

                    if (id == 2)
                        System.out.println("x: " + x + " y: " + y);

                    int[] tmb = {id, x, y};
                    ss.sendEveryone(tmb);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                run = false;
                clients.remove(this);
            }
        }
    }

    class SyncSend {
        public synchronized void sendEveryone(int[] a) throws SocketException {
            ArrayList<DataOutputStream> cl = (ArrayList<DataOutputStream>) clients.clone();
            Iterator<DataOutputStream> it = cl.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()){
                try {
                    DataOutputStream writer = (DataOutputStream) it.next();
                    writer.writeInt(a[0]);
                    writer.writeInt(a[1]);
                    writer.writeInt(a[2]);
                    writer.writeInt(id-1);
                    writer.flush();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new SocketException();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void init() {
        clients = new ArrayList<DataOutputStream>();

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5099);

            while(true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                DataOutputStream clientWriter = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                clients.add(clientWriter);
                clientWriter.writeInt(id);
                id++;

                Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ServerBase().init();
    }
}
```

What causes the delay? I've been searching for the reason for hours now, but with no success.

Comment: Left field idea: try using NIO...

Comment: So are you saying that once the client calls `writer.writeInt(ID)` that it takes 10 seconds before the server can read that data via `id = reader.readInt()`?  Have you inserted debugging statements that clearly indicate that this is where the slowdown is happening?  You may need to share a bit more of your code and/or work your code down to the minimal possible program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: My code is huge, even only the essential parts, but if it's nessecarry, I'll share it.

Comment: Surely you don't need all of the code to reproduce the problem, though, do you?  I would think a bare-bones socket-accept loop on the server side along with the `ClientHandler` pared down to just what you've shared thus far plus a minimal client would suffice.  It would really be helpful to have a minimal, complete example so we can build the code and see the problem happen for ourselves.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

You most likely need to call `flush()` on the client-side.  Even if this is not your current problem, it is probably a good idea.

Streams may buffer their content, meaning they may not send the data to its destination (whether that be a disk or over the wire to a server) the instant you call `write` (or `writeInt` in this case).  Instead, they may wait until they get a sufficient amount of data to make the transfer "worth it".  If they did not behave in this way, they would end up making lots of inefficient, smaller transfers.  The downside to all of this is that you may need to call `flush` to tell the stream that you are done sending data for a while and that the stream should go ahead and initiate the transfer.

Comment: Why? And why only on client side?

Comment: You should call flush on both sides, but you're seeing the delay on the client...

Comment: But why should I call it? Does it act like a buffer?

Comment: @LPeter1997 I updated my answer to address this question

Comment: And yes, I agree with mtyson, you should call it on both client and server sides, but since you are seeing the delay on the client side, start there and see if it that is your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the info but my problem is still the same.

Comment: @LPeter1997 `DataOutputStream` doesn't buffer, but if you have a `BufferedOutputStream` underneath it, which you should, the buffer is there. You didn't post enough client code for anyone else to know about this.

Answer (score 0):

try to put your codes into several threads everywhere you can and then call threads, I mean you don't need to wait for every **Socket** and simply run all of them at same time...or something like this :)

for example in Port Scanners, you should use many threads to speed up searching...

Comment: Every socket has it's own thread, this is only a part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that your call to `ss.sendEveryone(tmb)` is synchronized on the `ss` object.  I am assuming this is a `static` variable somewhere that holds a reference to all of the clients.  This means that if there are several clients sending data at the same time, a lot of calls to `sendEveryone` will happen all at once and they will all line up in a queue waiting for the others to finish, before those threads can go back and read more data from the client again.

As a diagnostic exercise, you may want to remove this call and see if you still have your problem.

Comment: It happens with only 2 clients and a server. If I remove synchronized, the sent data will be messed up.

Comment: Ok, that's good info to know.  I was definitely not advocating removing synchronized altogether, although it may not need to be quite as heavy-handed as it is...

Comment: @LPeter1997 Are you sure `System.nanoTime()` is accurate on your machine/OS?  According to the JavaDoc, there is no guarantee that it is any better than `System.currentTimeMilis()`.  I.e. - it could return a value like 253364334000000 for an entire millisecond, then return 253364335000000, and so on.  If this is true for your particular machine, then that would mean that `(now - lastTime)` would most likely be zero.

Comment: I'm sure, that the render and tick methods run 60 times a second. Checked.